# Premature captcha on wrong password

Tags: bug, login, captcha

#### Description

Every* day I try to login, by mistyping my password a first time, on the second attempt I'm directed to a captcha confirmation page.

#### Reproducing

1. Open the [login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) (being logged out, of course);
2. Type in your e-mail;
3. Type in a password that is not yours (such as "123456");
4. Hit "Log in";
5. Type in your actual password (such as "f1rst0n3_s#cks");
6. See the captcha.

---

Things I've already made sure of:

- My e-mail is correct;
- My password is correct *for the second attempt*;

Additional information (that I'm not sure is relevant):

- I use mainly incognito mode;
- * After the first successfull login, the isse goes away for some time (I didn't test in a time span shorter than a day) - maybe the server saves my IP(?).

---

#### My opinion

I'm not sure this is a bug. Personaly it's quite anoying. It's probably [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but IMHO, the captcha is **premature**. I mean, not even 1 mistake is allowed? Are we robots? How did we pass the captcha, then? xD

---

### Update

It's been brought to my attention that this seems to be a problem with my account specifically. I'm looking into it.

<sub><sup>I've linked this question in the contact I've made.</sup></sub>

Comment: Maybe this is not a bug but a feature-request? I'm not sure, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: *Every day I try to login, by mistyping my password a first time* ... well, don't do that?

Comment: @rene The action that happens on a daily basis is not the mistyping, but the login. Once in a while, I get it wrong. Anyways, that doesn't change the fact that the captcha is premature.

Comment: You should be thankful that the site serves captchas so liberally to people trying to login to your account because apparently your account has an *extremely* high number of failed login attempts, which is highly indicative of a user attempting unauthorized access to it.

Comment: @Servy I'm not saying remove the captcha completely, though. I'm saying that It's too strict to **not allow errors**.

Comment: @FirstOne No, you're just saying to serve it less often to an account that's consistently failing login checks, a pattern that's indicative of someone trying to guess the password, something that would be far easier for them if they got less captchas.

Comment: It does sound like a bug that on the second (and correct) attempt, hitting log in goes to captcha then back to the authentication page, where we have to hit log in again.

Comment: @Servy Then I don't have enough information to discuss this. But, if that's the case, I can't really test if this happens on an account that's not "under attack". Which makes me think about two things: 1- someone not "under attack" would have to test this and if the same behaviour is seen,  my point stands. 2- Where do I find that information about too many attempts?

Comment: I cannot repro this on my account (using Chrome in incognito mode). Like Servy already pointed out, the captcha may be coming directly after the first fail because you have many failed logins or because the network you use to access SO may generate high (login) traffic. About the fact that you are redirect wrongly after the correct login attempt, that may be an actual bug or design flaw

Comment: @doppelgreener I probably should remove that from the question. The main point is the premature captcha, not the flow.

Comment: @chade_ Me neither after a successfull login. So, test again tomorrow **before** login in, please ^^. (I assume you're logged in when you visited this question)

Comment: @FirstOne I have an [additional account for a chatbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9220325/checkyerflags) I maintain, and I haven't logged in with that recently IIRC.

Comment: @chade_ so we're getting somewhere here. Is there a way to access such information?

Comment: I just tried with my sock-puppet account and I can't repro either in FF. Do you have any plugins or scripts running that might contribute to what you see?

Comment: @rene highly unlikely since this happens in more than one computer with basically noting in common when it comes to extensions and such.

Comment: But when it happens you're on the same network/ISP or does that change as well?

Comment: @rene Different networks. Home / Work

Comment: @FirstOne About what? Last login? Or how many times it failed to login into your account? I think only SE employees can look up such data (But I'm not sure about that)

Comment: Hmm, at a minimum this needs a dev to check if your account is marked somehow

Comment: Thanks for the inputs so far, anyways :)